# Error authenticating in bigquery via python script

Tags: python, authentication, google-bigquery, interface

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(filename='GBQ.json',scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"])

contratos_final_agora_vai.to_gbq(credentials=credentials,destination_table='curso_etl.etl_csv', if_exists='replace',
table_schema=[{'name': 'data_inicio_vigencia', 'type': 'DATE'},
{'name': 'data_termino_vigencia', 'type': 'DATE'}])

### I have the following error:

Access Denied: Table dbt-shopsergio:curso_etl.etl_csv: Permission bigquery.tables.get denied on table dbt-shopsergio:curso_etl.etl_csv (or it may not exist).

Problem:
I need to access a database in Big Query via python.
I created the service account and gave it administrator permissions.
I can create the table, insert and query data directly in the Big Query interface, but when I try to run the python script I get an error.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Without seeing the full code, we cannot help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(filename='GBQ.json',
scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"])

contratos_final_agora_vai.to_gbq(credentials=credentials,destination_table='curso_etl.etl_csv', if_exists='replace', table_schema=[{'name': 'data_inicio_vigencia', 'type': 'DATE'},{'name': 'data_termino_vigencia', 'type': 'DATE'}])

When I go to connect the error occurs.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).